# Code implemented with HashMap fails when tested with array of size 30K

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on solving the code challenge from the link below but it fails from cases 13 to 19. 
I am reading that HashMap can take a large amount of data but my solution seems is not working for the cases when the array (magazine) is of 30K.

Below is the solution I implemented.

Help is appreciated.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps

I tested the code with arrays of 4K and it works fine

```
static void checkMagazine(String[] magazine, String[] note) {

    int initSize_m = (int) Math.ceil(magazine.length / 0.75);
    int initSize_n = (int) Math.ceil(note.length / 0.75);
    HashMap<Integer, String> m_hash= new HashMap<Integer, String>(initSize_m);
    HashMap<Integer, String> n_hash= new HashMap<Integer, String>(initSize_n);


    for(int i= 0; i < note.length; i++){
      n_hash.put(i, note[i]);
    }

    for(int i= 0; i < magazine.length; i++){
      m_hash.put(i, magazine[i]);
    }

    boolean flag=true;

    if(note.length<magazine.length){

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : n_hash.entrySet()) {
        flag = m_hash.containsValue(entry.getValue());
        if(flag){
            m_hash.values().removeIf(v -> v.equals(entry.getValue()));
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    }else{

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : m_hash.entrySet()) {
        flag = n_hash.containsValue(entry.getValue());
        if(flag){
            n_hash.values().removeIf(v -> v.equals(entry.getValue()));
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    }

    if(flag){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }else{
        System.out.print("No");
    }


}
```

Cases from 13 to 19 fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your maps should have the words as keys and their count as values. Mapping the words by their position in the input does not help you find them.

The whole point of a `Map` (also known as `Dictionary`) is to be able to quickly find a value by a given key. In the case of `HashMap` this operation is O(1), while finding a value by iterating all entry-values (as in your case) is much slower -> O(n). I strongly suggest that you read about maps and sets.

Here is a proper solution:

```
public class HackerRank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int numberOfWordsInMagazine = in.nextInt();
        final int numberOfWordsInNote = in.nextInt();

        final Map<String, Integer> wordsInMagazine = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWordsInMagazine; i++) {
            final String word = in.next();
            wordsInMagazine.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }


        boolean canPrintMessage = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWordsInNote; i++) {
            final String word = in.next();

            Integer remainingCount = wordsInMagazine.computeIfPresent(word, (key, value) -> value - 1);
            if (null == remainingCount || remainingCount < 0) {
                canPrintMessage = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(canPrintMessage ? "Yes" : "No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thanks for the push. My intention was to learn and I did.